# Android App Widget with SQlite query

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm working on an App Widget which is being updated by a service, started from the onUpdate() section of the AppWidgetProvider class. The problem is that whenever I use Cursors inside the widget service, the views are not being added to the widget. If I simply replace the sql query/result for a string, it works.

Not working example (using ContentProvider/SQL):

```
    public class TestWidgetService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TestWidget.class);

        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.test_widget
                    );

            // get items

            Uri items = Uri.parse(TestWidgetContent.CONTENT_URI + "/news/1");
            Cursor iCursor = getContentResolver().query(items, null, null, null, "ITM_TIMESTAMP DESC");
            if (iCursor == null) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (iCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (iCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                    Log.w("got", iCursor.getString(iCursor.getColumnIndex("FED_TITLE")));

                    RemoteViews item = new RemoteViews(
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.test_widget_item
                    );

                    item.setTextViewText(
                            R.id.test_widget_item_feed,
                            iCursor.getString(iCursor.getColumnIndex("FED_TITLE"))
                        );

                    item.setTextViewText(
                            R.id.test_widget_item_title,
                            iCursor.getString(iCursor.getColumnIndex("ITM_TITLE"))
                        );

                    remoteViews.addView(R.id.test_widget_items, item);

                    iCursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            iCursor.close();


            //

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }

        stopSelf();
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This example shows only the layout "test_widget" without the added views, even though the sql returns results and the views are added.

Working example (String only):

```
public class TestWidgetService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TestWidget.class);

        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.test_widget
                    );

            // get items

                    RemoteViews item = new RemoteViews(
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.test_widget_item
                    );

                    item.setTextViewText(
                            R.id.test_widget_item_feed,
                            "feed"
                        );

                    item.setTextViewText(
                            R.id.test_widget_item_title,
                            "title"
                        );

                    remoteViews.addView(R.id.test_widget_items, item);

            //

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }

        stopSelf();
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This working example shows the layout "test_widget" with the views inserted within the LinearLayout id "test_widget_items"

I have spent the last week trying to get this widget to use sql results, anyone has any slight idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I've just tried TestWidgetService.this.openOrCreateDatabase() instead of instantiating a complete DB helper class, but i got the same problem, the added views are not shown in the widget, even though the results are read correctly (and shown in the LogCat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the emulator, after removing the AVD snapshot and starting the app again, the widget was fine